# Accessing one class from another using id as parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

The association between class are as below

```
class Level < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :levels_users
end 

class LevelsUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :level
    has_many :schedules
end

class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :levels_user
end
```

I know the value of `level.id`. How do I find all schedules belonging to that `level.id`. `level.id` is the id of one of the level. I tried something like this:

```
Level.find(level.id).levels_users.schedule
```

But it won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `through` property of `has_many` association.

```
class Level < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :levels_users
  has_many :schedules, through: :levels_users
end
```

Now you can use

```
level.schedules
```